# unit test the function with callback passed to another function

Tags: node.js

I'm not sure what is the best way to do unit test for function foo, since the callback is passed to function bar, the unit test for foo I wrote is also testing the function bar.

Is there any way I could only test the logic inside the foo? In below use case, I just want to make sure foo function can increase value by 1 then pass everything to bar. How bar handle the value should be tested in bar unit test not foo unit test.

```
function bar(value, callback) {
    value = value + 1;
    callback(value);
}

function foo(value, callback) {
    value = value + 1;
    bar(value, callback);
}


//test for function bar
it('should be able to increase value by 1', function (done) {
    bar(1, function (value) {
    expect(value).to.equal(2);
    done();
  });
});

//test for function foo
it('should be able to increase value by 2', function (done) {
    foo(1, function (value) {
    expect(value).to.equal(3);
    done();
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is more or less analogous to the following synchronous code:

```
function bar(value) {
    value = value + 1;
    return value;
}

function foo(value) {
    value = value + 1;
    return bar(value);
}
```

Now that we're looking at something a little more familiar, we can ask your question again.  The answer, clearly, is no - `foo` always calls `bar`.

If you can test both `foo` and `bar`, it shouldn't matter - based on which of those fail, you can figure out where the error is.

If `bar` is something like a db call, which you might not be able to test, you should look into the idea of "mocking" functions/objects.  If `bar` isn't something that should be mocked, but `foo` should be tested without using `bar`, then this indicates that `bar` should probably be passed as an argument to `foo`, rather than hardcoded in to that function.

Comment: The sample code can be rewritten to the code you wrote, however as you guess, in my real use case, it is like a db call which needs to be mocked. could you please provide how you mock bar in my case above?

Comment: @siyang I would suggest looking into a library for mocking (searching npm should be instructive).  I've never done it in javascript, so I don't really have anything useful to contribute past giving you the keyword "mock".

Comment: I used sinon to stub the function and just wondering how other people do it. Thanks for you help!